# codeigniter how to load dynamic content with fix header and footer

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to load dynamic $content depend on get url in codeigniter with this php structure

```
 <?php 
        include_once "header.php";
        $content ='index-1.php';
        if(isset($_GET['p'])){
            switch($_GET['p']){
                case "room"      : $content="room.php" ;      break;
                case "room-page" : $content="room-page.php" ; break;
                case "book"      : $content="book.php" ;      break;
                case "about"     : $content="about.php" ;     break;
                case "contact"   : $content="contact.php" ;   break;    
            }
        }
        include $content;
        include_once "footer.php"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bellow controller function :

```
<?php    
public function index()
{
   //$data['page']['content'] = 'room';
   $data['page']['content'] = $this->input->get('page_name'); //like page name is "room"
   $this->load->view('welcome', $data);
}
?>
```

and then `welcome.php` in view folder :

```
<?php
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view($page['content']);
$this->load->view('footer');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that user has requested your main site url.

**Controller** Function

```
public function index()
{
  $data['page_name'] = $this->input->get('pageName');  
  $this->load->view('index', $data);
}
```

file in your **view** folder which in my case is **index.php** should look like this

```
<?php
   include 'header.php';
   include .$page_name.'.php';
   include 'footer.php';
?>
```

hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: hi does is it right that using View to load View not do it in Controller ? Again CI purpose  or ... ?

Comment: different guys do these stuff in different way... i did this in lot of my projects. So there is nothing wrong. I think this is the simplest way of doing what you asked for.